# Having troubling installing dlib with python3.5

Tags: macos, python-3.x, build, installation, dlib

I have tried to install dlib with sudo python3 setup.py install

and get

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared library dlib.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::python::detail::init_module(PyModuleDef&, void (*)())",  referenced from:
  _PyInit_dlib in dlib.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [dlib.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib_.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: cmake build failed!
```

I get this error with boost form brew, from boost.org boost1.60 and boost1.61

So I'm sure its not a boost issue... But I don't know why its giving this error

My computer is mac book pro OS X el captain 10.11.6

After install do I need to add another command for it to install?

So like sudo python3 setup.py install -something?

For it to install correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of dlib works! go to the website and download dlib from their. Once you have the file, then cd to the folder of dlib and python3 setup.py install. Thats all to it! The dlib version that works is 19.1

Comment: I have the same issue with 19.4 on macOS Sierra, with boost 1.63.0 compiled from sources.